# My first reaction "is that" I feel upset

Tags: that, compound-sentences

My first reaction is that I feel upset.
My first reaction is feeling upset.
My first reaction is to feel upset.
My first reaction is feel upset.

Which one is more appropriate or natural in what circumstance?

**Sorry, looking at the answers, I see that I wasn't able to explain myself properly. My question was NOT about the MEANING at all. I meant to ask about COMBINING PHRASES/SENTENCES with THAT as in the example below.**

**First phrase *is that* second phrase.**

Thank you.

Comment: It is a matter of opinion, but my opinion is that the first three are usable but the last is not grammatical and is not idiomatic.

Comment: [These Google ngrams for _reaction is that I feel, reaction is feeling, reaction is to feel_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reaction+is+that+I+feel%2Creaction+is+feeling%2Creaction+is+to+feel&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) echo my opinion that 'reaction is to feel ...' is most idiomatic.